# Swift: Add a label and place it underneath another label

Tags: swift, label, scrollview

I want to create labels programmatically with text that comes from a database.

So a for loop is creating the labels with this function at the moment:

```
    func fillScrollViewWithLabels() {
    for message in messages {

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        label.text = message.message
        self.chatScrollView.addSubview(label)

    }
}
```

But this function puts the labels one above the other.

It should look like a messenger - the labels are the text messages and I think a scrollView is perfect for that.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? (It's the default.) If you are, you'll need to create and add a set of constraints to your views, which is rather involved.

Comment: Declare a variable yPos outside loop and set it to 0 and increment it in loop with yPos+= height every time and user it in frame CGRectMake(0,yPos,200,21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make a variable for the Y position of your labels

```
var currentLabelYPosition : CGFloat = 0 // set to first y position
```

Then as you iterate through your array and create a label you'll need to get it's Y position based on the last labels Y position, like this:

```
for message in messages {

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, currentLabelYPosition, 200,21))
    label.text = message.message
    self.chatScrollView.addSubview(label)
    currentLabelYPosition + label.frame.size.height // Update this accordingly with any type of padding, offset, etc. 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your question but you're free to use Scrolview's subclass textview to store texts and than add different text in every message.

I suggest to check this [github repo](https://github.com/huyouare/SwiftParseChat) to familiarize concept of chat apps.

**Edit**

Also found this [notification chat github repo](https://github.com/relatedcode/NotificationChat) much more lightweight sample to examine.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

```
   var yPos:CGFloat = 0.0
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, yPos, 200, 21))
    for message in messages {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, yPos, 200, 21))
            label.text = message.message
            self.chatScrollView.addSubview(label)
            yPos = yPos+21;// you can also add spacing if you want
    }
```

Comment: i get `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UILabel' with an argument list of type '(frame: CGRect)'`

Comment: I updated my code you need to declare yPos like this  var yPos:CGFloat = 0.0